# Regular expressen that matches / but not //

Tags: regex, comments, match

For a custom syntax highlighting in "Sublime Text 2" I need a solution to regex the devisor "/" but not the double-slash comment "//"

example code for regex matching could look like this:

```
void main()
{
    int a = 10/2; // simple devision
    //        ^    ^ 
    //        |    +-- comment (the regex below will match the second slash)
    //        +-- devisor
}
```

my current regex looks like:

```
\/(?!\/)
```

The result of this regex matches also the second slash in the comment. How could I define a regex that **only** matches the devisor but does not touch the double slash comment at all?

Answer (score 1):

You were close. You specified a negative-lookahead assertion that a slash cannot *follow* a slash. And now you also need to specify a negative-lookbehind assertion that a slash cannot *precede* a slash.

```
(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)
```

Comment: Pro: this works with Sublime Text 2 - so thats the solution. Contra: this wont work with JavaScript, since Java Script does not support look behind.

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-matching character class:

```
[^\/]*(\/)[^\/]*
```

This will match any `/` that is not preceded or followed by another `/`.

Comment: This regex will expect there to be at least 1 character before and after the / and both characters will be part of the match. That may or may not be appropriate for this particular case, but by using zero-width negative lookahead and lookbehind assertions, the characters before and after the slash are not required and (if present) are not part of the match.

Comment: @SamChoukri How's that?

Comment: Well, now you've changed it to match zero-or-more non-slash characters before and after a single slash. That probably will match much more than the OP intended. One of the main advantages of lookahead/lookbehind assertions is that they are **zero width**, meaning they can be used to constrain what matches, but they are not actually part of the match. Your technique is not wrong...it just depends the situation.

Comment: @SamChoukri Gah. Fair enough.